# Specifying parameter constraints in nls()

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

Is it possible to specify that one parameter must be larger than another parameter in an nls call in my R script?

Here's my nls call:

```
fit <- nls(y ~ ifelse(g, m1 * (x - x0) + y0, m2 * (x - x0) + y0),
            start = c(m1 = -1, m2 = 1, y0 = 0, x0 = split),
            algorithm = "port",
            lower = c(m1 = -Inf, m2 = -Inf, y0 = -Inf, x0 = split),
            upper = c(m1 = Inf, m2 = Inf, y0 = Inf, x0 = (split+1)),
            data=data.frame(x,y))
```

It is finding values for the parameters m1, m2, x0, and y0. But I want to require that m2 must be LARGER than m1. How can I do this?

Comment: Because `g` evidently is a defined logical vector, rather than a parameter, this is an ordinary least square regression in which the intercept and slope are interacted with `g`.  Use `lm` to fit it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

However it seems you are using `nls` in a wrong way -- it will never work with non-differentiable functions. Can't you just fit two linear models to both parts of the data (i.e. `data.frame(x,y)[g,]` and `data.frame(x,y)[!g,]`)?

Comment: The objective function implicitly determined by this function *is* differentiable in all four parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could reparameterize $m_2$ by using the following

$$ m_{21} = m_2 - m_1$$

or

$$ m_{2} = m_1 + m_{21}$$

and then use the constrain $m_{21}>0$

```
fit <- nls(y ~ m1 * (x - x0) + y0 + ifelse(g,0 , m12 * (x - x0)),
        start = c(m1 = -1, m2 = 1, y0 = 0, x0 = split),
        algorithm = "port",
        lower = c(m1 = -Inf, m12 = 0, y0 = -Inf, x0 = split),
        upper = c(m1 = Inf, m12 = Inf, y0 = Inf, x0 = (split+1)),
        data=data.frame(x,y))
```